# Jsplumb dragging connection to top does not create scroll

Tags: jsplumb

How can I create scroll when I drag jsplumb connections to the top of the browser?
I searched through the net but couldn't find a solution to create scrolls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Click here to check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/14/)**

**JSPlumb or JQuery**

```
<script>

    var targetDropOptions = {

    };

    connectorHoverStyle = {
        lineWidth: 7,
        strokeStyle: "#2e2aF8",
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }

    //Setting up a Target endPoint
    var targetColor = "#316b31";
    var targetEndpoint = {
        anchor: "LeftMiddle",
        endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 8}],
        paintStyle: { fillStyle: targetColor },
        //isSource: true, 
        scope: "green dot",
        connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: targetColor, lineWidth: 8 },
        connector: ["Flowchart", { curviness: 63}],
        maxConnections: 1,
        isTarget: true,
        dropOptions: targetDropOptions,
        connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle
    };

    //Setting up a Source endPoint
    var sourceColor = "#ff9696";
    var sourceEndpoint = {
        anchor: "RightMiddle",
        endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 8}],
        paintStyle: { fillStyle: sourceColor },
        isSource: true,
        scope: "green dot",
        connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: sourceColor, lineWidth: 4 },
        connector: ["Flowchart", { curviness: 63}],
        maxConnections: 1,
        //            isTarget: true,
        dropOptions: targetDropOptions,
        connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle
    };
    jsPlumb.bind("ready", function () {

        jsPlumb.animate($("#A"), { "left": 50, "top": 100 }, { duration: "slow" });
        jsPlumb.animate($("#B"), { "left": 300, "top": 100 }, { duration: "slow" });
        var window = jsPlumb.getSelector('.window');
        jsPlumb.addEndpoint(window, targetEndpoint);
        jsPlumb.addEndpoint(window, sourceEndpoint);

        jsPlumb.draggable(window);

    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="A" class="a window" 
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px;">
    <strong>A</strong>
</div>
<div id="B" class="b window" 
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px;">
    <strong>B</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle but it is has the problem which i have when you drag the object to top it is hidden it does not create scroll.

Comment: I want that my object either create scroll when i move object to top of browser or it should stop and should not hide itself.

Comment: No offense, but question is not really answered. Seems a hot topic because none of the stack overflow posts since 2 years provide a clear answer.

Comment: jsfiddle is not working. Which change in the above code actually solved the issue..?

Comment: https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/212.. this is working for me. But scroll won't work. But user won't be able to drag beyond the boundary in top and left side.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have one div with the properties position:relative and overflow:scroll and all shapes inside of this one make scroll up and down. I hope can help you.